# D3.js + Enclose Nodes of Directed Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm newer to D3 and have used this example here

http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347

to create nodes and links for my DB data. What I would like is for nodes above a certain number to be contained inside of another circle to signify that they are part of a group, somewhat like this

[image]

Is there a proven method or trick doing something like this?

Comment: Nope. This isn't supported directly. You could combine a pack layout with a force layout, but that's not going to be trivial.